# Mongodb schema design for optimum search performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Currently i'm implementing a web application using MEAN stack. According to my business logic (same business logic as fiverr.com)

- there can be multiple services
- one service can have millions of service providers
- one provider can provide many services
- users should be able to search service providers based on average_cost and location.
- Searching  providers should be very quick. (must use the optimum approach)

My current approach is

- keep service details and provider details in separate schemas
- reference Providers in Service document with details required to search ( average_cost, location)
- select suitable Provider _ids from the service document ( based on average_cost and location)
- then get complete documents of Providers using selected _ids.

Here is my service schema

```
  var ServiceSchema = new Schema({ 

      service: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            index: true, 
            required: true
      }
      providers :[{
            _id:false,
            provider: {
                   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                   ref: "Provider"
            },
            average_cost:{
                   type: String,
                   default: null
            },
            location:{
                   type: String,
                   default: null
            }
      }] 
  });
```

Here is my Provider schema

```
var ProviderSchema = new Schema({

  _id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },


  basic_info: {

              business_name: {
                  type: String,
                  required: true
              },

              discription :{
                  type: String,
                  default: null
              },
              tagline :{
                  type: String,
                  default: null
              }
    }
});
```

my problem is, in a service document providers array can contain millions of objects.
since in Mongodb maximum document size is 16MB, millions of objects may exceed that limit. So I don't think this is a good schema design.

Can anyone please suggest me a good schema design.

Comment: Does single provider provide only one service? And if not, up to how many?

Comment: no single provider can provide many services. it depends on the available services. basically a provider can provide all the services if he wants.

Comment: Any chance you can go SQL? If you want quick search on not-so-few-to-many relationship, it's going to be better in case there are many of *not-so-few*.

Comment: I have already implemented half of the application. some functionalities requires Schema less design. So i will need a solution from Mongodb

Comment: Who defines the services? Do the providers define them? Do the services have a lifetime? How many services can a single provider offer? And please define Location more thoroughly. Vicinity? Area of coverage of individual providers? Delivery area/times?

Comment: services are defined by us (administrator). providers cannot define them. but they can set their own average_costs and locations. Services doesn't have a life time. it's just providers attached to a service so they appear in search results when someone search on a particular service. we are not going to limit the number of services that one provider can have. but practically it wil be less than 20.

Comment: Same business logic as fiverr.com